# Пуговица — от какого слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Есть ли общее в словах "пуговица" и "пугать"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, слова совсем не родственны.
В отношении этимологии слова "пуговица" словари расходятся, но несомненно, что оно несет очень древний индоевропейский морф, сохранившийся во многих славянских в сходном русскому значениях. 
При этом надо отметить варианты: стар. **пугвица**, др.-русск. **пугъвь, пугы**, сербск.-цслав. **пѫгы, -ъве**.

"Пугать", вероятно производное от пужать, пудити (с тем же значением), фонетика исключает родственность "пѫг" и "пуд" - это совершенно разные основы.

*ѫ - юс великий, эта буква передавала носовой звук, перешедший в русском в У (после мягких - в Я).*

Answer (score 0):

да прям-таки, а то, что пуговица прежде служила оберегом, отпугивающим злых духов, тут совсем ни при чем??